# Database design question (FK to different tables)

Tags: database-design, rdbms

Consider a shopping cart, allowing customers to use variable payment systems.

Each system has a different set of parameters: system A has such attributes as reference id, xml response, transaction id, system B has transaction id and a status, system C (Cheque) has only payment date. Statuses differ in every system as well.

On the payment system selection page there are name and description of the payment system, which are to be stored in the database too (e.g. not hardcoded to HTML).

How would you design the database?

The best thing I can think about is having a table for every system + a table for payment system descriptions linking to the name of the relevant table + 2 extra fields in the orders table: payment system id (will link to "description table"), payment record id (will link to the id in the relevant payment system table). This would also allow to provide specific functionality (order notifications processing etc.) to be separated among payment system models instead of using `if`s. Is it ok?

If anything, the project is based on PHP 5, Doctrine and MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably you could have a main System table that contains any common information (an id, a name, whatever) and then a second table that collects name/value pairs for the attributes:

```
CREATE TABLE system_table
(id int,
name char(50),
...
);

CREATE TABLE system_properties
(system_id int,
name char(50),
value varchar
);
```

This might be unattractive to people because of the fuzzy mapping of properties but on the other hand getting the properties for any system becomes a simple join rather than trying to pull a handful of tables together.

Please note that the SQL create statements above are pseudocode-ish.

Answer (score 1):

One table for each *type* of payment system - the type being a unique set of attributes common to one or more payment system. Have a parent table of all those types that contains attributes shared by all of them (for instance the system name).

Answer (score 0):

What dportas and jaydel said plus my two cents.

Each payment system should be in a row of a table, not in a table of its own.  Each type of payment system (speacialized payment system) needs a table of its own for data that is only collected for that type.

In addition, there should be a generic payment system table containing data that pertains to all types of payment systems.

The relationship betwee the generic payment system table and the specialized payments system tables is a classic "gen=spec desing pattern".  If you look up "generalization specialization relational modeling" you will find articles that teach you how to design relational tables for the gen-spec pattern.

The short answer is that the gen table has a classic ID field acting as a PK.  Each specialized table has an ID field that is a duplicate of the ID field in the gen table.  This means that it is both a PK in the specialized field and a FK referencing the gen table.

FK references to a payment system elsewhere in the database should reference the gen table.